# Double Pointers Queue, deQueue, enQueue

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, queue, double-pointer

Currently preparing for exams and can't figure out the reasoning behind the queue[rear*] = new_node in this example code.

are you not putting the address of new_node in rather than the value?

Also, is the queue a Node ** queue because it is a pointer to a list of node pointers?

Thanks so much, I really appreciate it, no matter how many hours i spend on double pointers, they always crop up and retest my understanding i thought i finally had!

```
void enQueue(struct node **queue, int *rear, struct node *new_node) 
{ 
queue[*rear] = new_node; 
(*rear)++; 
} 

struct node *deQueue(struct node **queue, int *front) 
{ 
(*front)++; 
return queue[*front - 1]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable `rear` is a pointer to an `int`. With `*rear` you get the value of that `int`. That value is then used as index.

It's equivalent to e.g.

```
int index = *rear;
queue[index] = new_node;
index++;
*rear = index;
```

It copies the value of the variable `new_node` (i.e. the address of where the pointer is pointing) into `queue[index]`. From this point onward, both `new_node` and `queue[index]` points to the same thing.

I hope that makes it clearer what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Here `queue` is pointer to pointer to array of `struct Node pointers`.

Where each `node` pointer inside the array will point to NewNodes.

```
              node 1              node2
               ^                  ^
               |       ....       |
           +--------+---------+--------+
  queue -->| node * | node *  |node *  |
           +--------+---------+--------+
```

When you do

```
       queue[*rear] = new_node;
```

You assign the `node *` at the `*rear` position inside the `queue` array to `NewNode`

Only reason I can think of for maintaining the `Node *` array is to avoid the copying the content of `NewNode`.